# Loading texture from Web Worker in Three.js

Tags: javascript, multithreading, three.js, textures, web-worker

When applying a large texture image to a Mesh for a noticeable period of time Three.js locks-up browser's main thread. Let's consider the following example:

```
var texLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

texLoader.load('someLargeTexture.jpg', function(texture) {
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, 32, 32);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture});
    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    // adding the object to the scene will lock up the browser's main thread
    scene.add(sphere);
});
```

I also noticed the following:

- no thread lock-up occurs if the new object **is not** added to the scene
- changing the geometry of an object doesn't cause lock-up
- if a new object is created with a material borrowed from an existing object (which already is in the scene) will **will not cause** lock-up
- assigning a new material to an existing object (which already is in the scene) **will causes** lock-up

My conclusion is that Three.js does some work on a material at point at which it's added to the scene. The result is the cached and later re-used.

The question is if this work can somehow be offloaded to web worker, so that the main thread doesn't get locked-up?

The worker could look like this:

```
var texLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

texLoader.load('someLargeTexture.jpg', function(texture) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture});

    // ... long-running work goes here ...

    // adding the object to the scene will lock up the browser's main thread
    self.postMessage({
        msg: 'objectCreated',
        material: material.toJson(), // converting material to JSON
    });
});
```

Then in the main thread we could do:

```
var worker = new Worker('worker.js');

worker.addEventListener('message', function(ev) {
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, 32, 32);

    // converting JSON back to material object
    var material = MaterialLoader.prototype.parse( ev.data.material );

    // this should't lock-up the main thread
    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    scene.add(sphere);
});
```

Can something like this be done?

Comment: You can use browser debugging tools to take a timeline snapshot of this loading operation. For example in Chrome you will see method X taking Y seconds. This should show you where the bottleneck is. If it's where THREE.js sends the texture to the GPU, then there may not be anything you can do, other than use a smaller texture, or split it up across several materials.

Answer (score 2):

Just run into this issue while trying to load textures in parallel with workers. Main roadblock seems to be THREE.Texture holds a reference to the <img> (DOM element) which in turn holds the actual image data. Don't know of a way to serialize an <img>, also [webgl accepts <img> as texture data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Using_textures_in_WebGL). So there is no need for THREE to touch it.

A solution might be to use a THREE.DataTexture, but that involves turning possibly compressed images into uncompressed RGB. Unfortunately a detour via a <canvas> drawImage() + getImageData() is not possible, because workers can't deal with DOM elements.

Eventually I've decided parallel texture loading has to wait for [the-offscreen-canvas-interface](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#the-offscreencanvas-interface).

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/spite/THREE.UpdatableTexture and https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/11846 would be of interest?

Comment: @WestLangley, indeed can't await r87.