# Web workers for loading object in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, web-worker

I'd like to load and parse a 3D file using three.js and the corresponding Loader (e.g. PLYLoader).  However, because my 3D files are very large, the Loader spends a long time parsing the file and locks up all JS-based UI on the page.  I was wondering what the best way to load the file would be without locking the UI.

I imagine the solution is based on web workers.  However, I'm not sure about what the best way to approach it is.  The Loaders require the main three.js file, which in turn performs DOM manipulations.  Therefore, I cannot naively just copy the Loader functionality into its own web-worker file.

I found that a similar question was asked previously.  However, the answer seems to be specifically directed in the case of textures, which appear to have differences in web-worker applicability.

[Loading texture from Web Worker in Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43341757)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually can include the loading functionality into a web worker. Just import three.js and the respective loader file:

```
myWorker.js
...
importScripts('/path/to/js/three.js', '/path/to/js/threeXYZLoader.js');
```

After that you can load your object just as described in the [Three.js example.](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/OBJLoader)
The trickier part is to get your loaded object back into your main thread in order to be rendered. Have a look at this approach using [Worker.postMessage and Transferable object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48620639/1171425) as a starting point.

Comment: OP stated in their question that they can't include three.js lib in the worker because it needs access to the DOM. Are you saying it's actually not a problem?

Comment: Right it is not a problem unless you create a renderer and a scene. Just for using the loader functionality you actually can include the three.js file. I use it the same way in my application. I also load my models from within a web worker context and I can confirm that this works.

Comment: It turns out that the loader I was using performed some scene manipulations for whatever reason, which was causing the DOM updates.  I messed around with your suggestions and I managed to get it to work.  Thanks!

Comment: As correctly stated by OP, even the object loaders require access to DOM as they generate image elements for loading textures